# Should the [using] tag be burninated?

Tags: support, tags, meta-tags

There are useful specific tags for [using-statement](/questions/tagged/using-statement) and [using-directives](/questions/tagged/using-directives).

Questions tagged simply [using](/questions/tagged/using) either should be using one of those, or else had an actual sentence typed into the tags line "using code to send packets" where the tag isn't helping anything.

Does anyone see a legitimate need for this tag?  Are there other meanings of `using` that require the creation of new clarifying tags besides the two mentioned?

Vote here for burnination!

[image]

Comment: No - it's not something that a user can be an expert in, so I'd say kill the tag.  Also, [this](http://i.imgur.com/MJAxd.png) might go well with your question.

Comment: Seems like a candidate for disambiguation rather than a straight up burnination... though with 400 questions in it it'd be a bit rough. Would questions in the tag benefit from either [tag:using-statement] or [tag:using-directives]?

Comment: @Anna: Did you miss the first sentence of the question?  No, because you just cleaned up my markup.  So I fail to understand your comment.

Comment: @BenVoigt No, I didn't. I'm asking if it'd be beneficial to go through 400 questions and retag them. Burninating [tag:using] will just remove it, which is fine if it's a useless tag, but will that make the tags on those questions less useful as a result?

Comment: I already retagged a handful.  Maybe we need a drag-and-drop tag disambiguation tool.

Comment: Yeah, if the tag carries meaning (even if it's not quite the right tag and there are better options), burninating is unfortunately not the way to go.

Comment: Or maybe burnination needs to add a message in the inbox of the owner of each affected question... with some alternate tags suggested by the burninator.

Answer (score 3):

Quite a few of those questions seem to be tagged with `using` because the user just typed that they want to “do this *using* that” in the tags. (I hate that!) Not all though; it needs someone to go through and audit first, and I don't think that that's something that a computer can do for you very well. Manual effort definitely required.

But once the selected migrations to the right tag are done, burninate it!